# does getMeasuredHeight() return values in pixels or dp

Tags: android, listview, view

i am trying to get the height of the items in a listview programmatically. so i referred to som epost in our website and i came out with following code

```
    private float calcListViewItemsHeight(ListView listView) {
    Log.d(TAG, getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(listView.getId()) + ".getCount() :" + listView.getCount());

    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
        View childView = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView);
        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        height+= childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    //dividers height
    height += listView.getDividerHeight() * listView.getCount();

    Log.d(TAG, getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(listView.getId()) + "totalHeight in px: " + height);

    float dp = this.px2dp(height);
    Log.d(TAG, getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(listView.getId()) + "totalHeight in dp: " + dp);

    return dp;
    //return height;
}
```

the value returned from the above code, supposedly to be in pixels, which mean i have to convert it into dp so my code can work fine on different screen sizes.
to convert from pixels to dp i used the followin gcode:

```
private float px2dp(int pxVal) {
    float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    return (pxVal/ density);
}
```

now, as my list contains 4 items, i get the following logCat output which represents the number of the items contains in the listview and the height of the listview in both pixels and dp, this reults comes from 
'calcListViewItemsHeight' posted above

```
12-10 10:27:40.817 D/VersDetailActivity2: versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_versDetails.getCount() :4
12-10 10:27:40.822 D/VersDetailActivity2: versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_versDetailstotalHeight in px: 533
12-10 10:27:40.822 D/VersDetailActivity2: versicherungsListeActivity2mod_lisVie_versDetailstotalHeight in dp: 266.5
```

what i could not understand is, when the method 'calcListViewItemsHeight' returns 'height' i got the listview of a height as shown in img_1, but if 'calcListViewItemsHeight' returned 'dp' i got a listview of height
as shown in img_2

does 'getMeasuredHeight()' returns value in dp or pixels?

**img_1**:

[image]

**img_2**:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight()) said that the return value is "The raw measured height of this view." And from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/Dimension) "raw" means **pixels**. And may be [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) link also helps You.

Answer (score 0):

`childView.getMeasuredHeight();` will returns the height in `px`.

```
private float calcListViewItemsHeight(ListView listView){
```

In this function, you are calculating the total height of the `ListView`.
And the calculated `height` will be in px.and you are converting `height` (in px) to `dp`(in dp).

I want to know that, where you are applying these results?.

the value in `px` is larger than that in `dp`.thats why in first case the `ListView` larger than the second one.

You have to give the `ListView` height in `px`, not in `dp`.AFAIK, values in `dp` is applicable in the xml files only.

Comment: thanks for the provided info...would you please have a look at this question as well    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074602/regarding-understanding-the-layout-units